# The version of my site that is not preferred appears to have better health in Google Search Console

Tags: google-search-console

I have set `www` version as preferred in Google Search Console. I haven't touched the `non-www` version for a long time.  I use only the `www` version for sitemap uploading, error fixing and setting structured data.

However, in Google Search Console my `non-www` site is in the first place when sorted by property health. Why would that be?

Comment: The preferred domain is not selected https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/44231?hl=en

Comment: no i have selected the preferred domain to www version , that's why I'm asking this question

Comment: Use canonical https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en

Comment: I also have solved the canonical problem by 301 redirecting  non-www version to www version. so there is no point of having a canonical tag. but still problem remains.

Comment: How long has it been? Often, implementing a 301 redirect from one site to another takes quite some time to sort out in the search engines.

Comment: When you examine both, does Google give you different information about them? For example, indexed pages, linking domains, etc. I recommend going through both accounts, each one open in its own tab, and comparing apples to apples on each page. (If you haven't done so already.)

Comment: yes, Henry both having significant differences.  preferred version doing well and the other version has very poor results.  that's why I'm wondering why still that domain remains as the good health domain.

Comment: Do you mean that in your Search Console page that lists both your domains, the poor health domain is shown at the top? If so, that's intentional, you should be good, it seems: https://searchengineland.com/google-adds-site-health-to-webmaster-tools-home-page-95085

Comment: yes  Henry  you are correct i have listed both and poor health one is on top. since search console take time to update i will wait and see. thank u

Comment: That's the thing, @VinoliSenanayake - your healthy website will keep showing up below the other one, because that's how Google orders them. Check out the Search Engine Land link I posted above. In this scenario, it's a good thing that your intended site is listed below the other one - it means it's fine, you don't have a website issue.

Answer (score 1):

A live version of a website is almost always going to have errors and other negative "site health" issues.

By comparison a domain that automatically redirects to another version (www in this case) has zero errors, zero HTML improvements that are needed, etc.

Accordingly the (very poorly implemented) sort by Site Health is pretty useless and no cause for concern.

Comment: ok i got that , hot it will be fixed by time

Comment: It will never be fixed as far as I know until they adjust the way the sorting is done unfortunately.

Comment: ah ok ok unless it won't affect my site that's fine.